# python scatterplot annotation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a small scatterplot project and it's coming together as well as could be but i want to add the name column to the corresponding dots in the scatterplot. Can someone help me because i can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("moneynuts.csv", index_col=0)
columns = df.columns

def clean_stringy_number(num: str) -> str:
    
    if num == "-":
        return "0"

    num = num.replace(",", "")

    return num


df.dropna(subset=['Gls'], inplace=True)

df.dropna(subset=['xG'], inplace=True)
#df.sort_values(by=['Gls', 'xG'])

df["Gls"] = df["Gls"].apply(clean_stringy_number)   

df["Gls"] = df["Gls"].apply(int)
df["xG"] = df["xG"].apply(clean_stringy_number)
df["xG"] = df["xG"].apply(float)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row["Gls"] == "-" or row["Gls"] == "0"):

        df['Gls'].dtypes
        if (row["xG"] == "-" or row["xG"] == "0"):

            continue
        continue
    print (row["Name"], " average goals of ", row["Gls"], " With an xG of ", row["xG"])
    
    
    try:
        gls = float(row["Gls"].replace(",", "."))
        xG = float(row["xG"].replace(",", "."))
    except:
        print("Unknown char")


df["xG"] = df["xG"] / 100


sp = df.plot.scatter(x='Gls',
                     y='xG')
x_values = df["Gls"].astype(int)
plt.xticks(range(x_values.min(), x_values.max()+1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: try asigning the converted data back to the row -> `row["Gls"] = float(row["Gls"].replace(",", "."))` and
        `row["xG"] = float(row["xG"].replace(",", "."))` not sure if that is all.

Comment: Also delete line `df['Gls'].dtypes` it doesn't do anything in that context.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).